# How to use answers package if there are sub parts and sub-sub-parts in the question

Tags: lists, answers

I want to use `answers` to produce solution files for questions with parts, subparts, sub-sub-parts.  Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
%\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{enumerate}{ans}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\arabic*),leftmargin=*,labelindent= \parindent,widest=99),align=left}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\alph*),leftmargin=*,labelindent=   \parindent,widest=a),align=left}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*),leftmargin=*,labelindent=\parindent,widest=viii),align=left}
\newcommand{\enumerateparams}{\relax}
%The previous line is required when solution file is produced. An `\enumerateparams' is added to every \begin{enumerate}. Without this an error message is produced.
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\begin{Filesave}{ans}
\begin{center}
    {\bfseries\large Marking Scheme\\
        MMTE-006 }\\
    2018  \end{center}
{\bfseries The solution presented in the marking scheme may be one of the possible solutions. Marks may be given for any other correct solution.}
\restartlist{enumerate}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{resume}
\end{Filesave}
\section{Problems}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First exercise
  \begin{enumerate}
   \item exercise 1. Part a
   \item part b\begin{enumerate}
               \item part b sub-part i)
              \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\begin{sol}\item
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Part a solution.
     \item part b 
     \begin{enumerate}
     \item Solution of part b),  sub-part i)
     \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate} 
\end{sol}
\item Second exercise
\begin{sol}
 \item Second solution.
\end{sol}
\end{enumerate}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
 [image]

However, when solution files are not produced and the solutions are included inline, there is a problem with list number.(Comment the lines `\usepackage{answers}`, `\input{ans1}` and remove the comment from the line `\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}`)    The numbering to solutions start with a) and goes on to i), A) etc, instead of 1), a), i) etc. Here is the output:
[image]
Can this be fixed?